# Hit a curb pretty violently while making a turn, doing 10 mph. Don't see a bubble on tire. Is there still a chance of internal damage to the sidewall?

Tags: tires, wheels, suspension, alignment

Any chance a wheel bearing might've been damaged? I was going slow but, did hit it pretty hard.

Although these wheels (18's on low profile tires) have cracked before from potholes, the rim and tire do SEEM fine though.

Replace tire/ wheel or what?

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no way to know as visible damage is often only from the inside. Your wheel and tire could be fine and good to go for thousands of miles, or they could disintegrate today when you're going 70mph. Take it to a reputable tire shop and pay for an inspection, it's the only way you'll have any assurance.